# Generic Routing match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)' not available in Rails 4. Way Out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

As far as I read, I understood that Rails 4 doesn't support **match** keyword.

But I want to make a default generic route something like following

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)', :via => :get
```

When I use above code in routes.rb, it throws me following error:

```
Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes
```

Can someone help me how to implement this in Rails 4.

Comment: it is supported http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints

Comment: Did you faced any errors using match

Comment: About 2 days ago I tried (with Rails 4.1.13) `match '*all' => 'cors#reject', via: :options` and it works as expected, so I suppose `match` is still alive, at least in Rails 4.1.

Comment: Yes I did get error !! Pasted it in heading. Basically when I add this ---           match ':controller(/:actions(/:id))', :via => :get           ---- in routes.rb, server returns following --------       error: Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes       ------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is supported, from the [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide

**3.7 HTTP Verb Constraints**

In general, you should use the get, post, put, patch and delete methods to constrain a route to a particular verb. You can use the match method with the :via option to match multiple verbs at once:

> match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: [:get, :post]

You can match all verbs to a particular route using via: :all:

> match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: :all

and from the documentation:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match

```
# sets :controller, :action and :id in params
match ':controller/:action/:id', via: [:get, :post]
```

If you add this line to your routes:

```
match ':controller/:action/(:id)', via: :get
```

it will produce the following route:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                        Controller#Action
       GET  /:controller/:action(/:id)(.:format) :controller#:action
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But why is it returning the error `Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes`.

Comment: @Rusty Have you the same exact code as this example? I've edited and add the result.

Comment: Yes I have exact same code. I have this code in **route.rb** and 1 folder named **demo** in views with two files named *hello.html.erb** and *index.html.erb** in **demo** folder. But when I tried your code `match ':controller/:action/:id', via: :get` and tried **http://localhost:3000/demo/index** in my browser, it returned following error `No route matches [GET] "/demo/index"`. I am using Rails 4.2.4.

Comment: @Rusty Do you have a DemoController with an index method?

Comment: This is my DemoController Code 

`class DemoController < ApplicationController
  layout false
  def index
  end
end`  You will understand the indentation ^_^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89875/discussion-between-rusty-and-paulo-fidalgo).